# Title "Experienced" vs. "Senior"

Tags: title

I noticed lately that people start to use "Experienced" Adjective in Job Titles. I have the impression this replaces the usage of Senior. Can you confirm there is a trend.

For example on LinkedIn there are >50k profiles [matching "Experienced" in the Job title](https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/p?title=Experienced). And those are not limited to freelancers.

If yes, is there a canonical piece (article) which prompted this movement, or is it just a natural trend given the unclear definition of Senior title (i.e. is it based on responsibilities, years at the job, age or others).

I also wonder: are companies using "experienced" as part of the official work title (like Senior, Lead, Managing, .. etc). I.e. can you name companies where there is regulation on when such an attribute is made official on the business card or are all those thousands of job descriptions using "Experienced" only self proclaimed (or freelancers).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37497/discussion-on-question-by-eckes-title-experienced-vs-senior).

Answer (score 6):

As regards Senior, there are specifics I would expect of someone in my teams:

- Self management - managing their own time on a project to meet deadlines, keep busy, work efficiently etc.
- A level of managing/mentoring - being able to oversee one or two junior members of the team either on specific tasks  or projects.

Experienced doesn't really mean anything other than you've been doing a role/ skill for a number of years, but we all know people with 20 years who have been doing the same year 20 times, so that doesn't always tell us anything useful.

Comment: Actually the same argument applies to Senior, dont you think?

Comment: Senior is a well recognised title that is often misused, but I agree with this being roughly it's supposed meaning. Experienced is meaningless (as far as I know).

Comment: @eckes - well you can call yourself anything of course, but if you came to one of my teams as a (or to take a) Senior role, I'd expect you to have/be able to do the above.  If you say your experienced, I'd just say you'd be listening to Jimi Hendrix ;)

Comment: To me "senior" implies "more than others" as far as a team goes. Wheras "experienced" is just a generic qualifier. For example, your team has 4 *experienced* professionals, but maybe just one or two are considered "senior". That's all.

Comment: @Brandin - not necessarily, I've had teams where all the members were "Senior" due to skills, experience and authority, it's not as staright forward as say "Lead" is.

Comment: +1 for "we all know people with 20 years who have been doing the same year 20 times" I knew someone on another site who used to say that all the time.